# Folder to put under revision control linux workstation

Tags: linux, backup, arch-linux, opensuse

I have several Linux workstations, including servers on which I often make critical changes and would be happy to be able to roll back them in case I break something.

I therefore consider versioning critical folders like `/etc` but I was wondering if other folders are important to keep under revision control. What would be your policy?

What I would include as as start in this policy is:

- Do not version `/var/log` or other always changing folders (do you have other examples?)
- Version `/etc`
- Do not nest repositories
- Version all critical services configuration outside of `/etc`, any idea?

It would be great if more rules could be found, otherwise I can give more details about my specific problem:

- I am using Arch Linux on my workstations and laptops
- I am using OpenSuse on the servers I am responsible of
- These servers are production servers, meaning if I break the apache server on them and cannot quickly rollback them I leave all my coworkers in the dark.
- I use [git](http://git-scm.com/) as a revision control for our source code, but if another system is more suited to this task I would take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is reasonably common for sysadmins to keep system config under version control.

The simplest method is to use [`etckeeper`](http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/), which can do this with minimal manual setup and can interface with several different VCSs. It's reasonably well known (is probably in your distributions' repositories; [was described in the official Ubuntu Server docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/etckeeper.html), ...)

Some advantages of using it rather than manually maintaining your VCS repository:

> It hooks into apt (and other package managers including yum and pacman-g2) to automatically commit changes made to /etc during package upgrades. It tracks file metadata that revison control systems do not normally support, but that is important for /etc, such as the permissions of /etc/shadow.

(from the homepage's description).

For a discussion of `etckeeper` alternatives (aimed at sysadmins), see also [this question on Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3750/version-control-for-etc-under-bsd).

System-wide configuration is *supposed* to go in `/etc/` on Debian-like systems at least; I assume it's similar for other distributions. As long as the programs you have installed are well-behaved, your critical services should have their configuration in `/etc/`.